# Global objects best practices in express js application running multi core machines

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pm2

I am confused with using global variables in my express js application which will be running on multiple core machines (it can be done with pm2).

here are my approaches

**1)Global variable**

`global.db = new Sequelize('ICG_dev','root','root')`

Access to other files with `global.db`

**2)module.exports**

`module.exports.db  = new Sequelize('ICG_dev','root','root');`

Access to other files with

```
 const db = require ('db.js');

   db.get()
```

What are the pros and cons of the above two methods if I am running my application on multiple core machines

Comment: Ever had to debug some obscure code, and you found out that the problem is related to one variable being modified somehow by some other code? Now you had to  find the source of that modification in a huge project ... TLDR: global variables are bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you're running your application on multi-core machines with pm2 is completely irrelevant to the question. Each Node.js process will be distinct. pm2 just runs multiple processes. Globals (and loaded modules) will not be shared across those processes.

So the question is really: Is it better to have a global variable, or export something from a module that other modules can import via `require`?

It's up to you, but overwhelmingly, I'd say the community has come down on the side of: Use the module.

Comment: in short  my second method is better than the first one?